# Decrypt the string in VC++ which has been encrypted in C#.Net

Tags: c#, visual-c++, encryption

I want to decrypt the string which has been encrypted by an application in C#.Net by using the following methods:

```
      public static class clsEncryptions
{
    public static string GetKey()
    {
        var key = new { key = "MyKey" };
        return key.key;
    }

    public static string Encrypt(this string EncryptString)
    {
        if (EncryptString == string.Empty)
            return string.Empty;
        byte[] clearBytes =
          System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(EncryptString);
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(GetKey(),
            new byte[] {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 
        0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76});

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
        alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
        cs.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }


    public static string Decrypt(this string DecryptString)
    {
        if (DecryptString == string.Empty)
            return string.Empty;
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(DecryptString);
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(GetKey(),
                        new byte[] {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 
        0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76});
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
        alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
        cs.Close();
        return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Please help me to convert the Decryption Logic in to VC++(MFC project) so that i could be able to read the encrypted file in my VC++ application.

Comment: You obviously need a [C++ implementation of Rijndael](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at those

1. http://www.cryptopp.com/  this is C++ encryption library that will help you
2. http://pocoproject.org/  this is a c++ framework that has encryption classes that you will need

my advice is to use cryptopp to get smaller application size, but poco is easier in code writing and produce a bigger exe size in static linking, that what i noticed this may not be correct.